# argument "no" is missing, with no default in R

Tags: r, variables

I have been trying to create a new variable that categorises whether a participants has diabetes based on the data from another variable but I keep getting the message : Error in ifelse(glyhb >= 7, "no") :
argument "no" is missing, with no default.

For instance, a diagnosis of diabetes is made if glycosolated haemoglobin (glyhb) > 7.0.

I tried this code but it isn't working:

```
Diabetes$diabetes <- with(Diabetes, ifelse(glyhb > 7, "yes", ifelse(glyhb >=7, "no")))
```

I was wondering where I am going wrong?

Comment: The second `ifelse` does not have else option. Try `Diabetes$diabetes <- with(Diabetes, ifelse(glyhb > 7, "yes", ifelse(glyhb >=7, "no", NA)))`. Also do you need two `ifelse` ? `Diabetes$diabetes <- with(Diabetes, ifelse(glyhb > 7, "yes", "no"))` will do ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `glyhb >=7` is true. I think for no Diabetes it should be `glyhb <=7`.

**`ifelse`** https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse

Usage: `ifelse(test, yes, no)`

`ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

In case my thinking is correct, then see this example:

```
# fake data
Diabetes <- structure(list(glynb = 1:20), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# base R:
Diabetes$has_diabetes <- ifelse(Diabetes$glynb > 7, "yes", "no")

# dplyr:
library(dplyr)
Diabetes %>% 
  mutate(has_diabetes = ifelse(glynb > 7, "yes", "no"))
```

Output:

```
   glynb has_diabetes
   <int> <chr>       
 1     1 no          
 2     2 no          
 3     3 no          
 4     4 no          
 5     5 no          
 6     6 no          
 7     7 no          
 8     8 yes         
 9     9 yes         
10    10 yes         
11    11 yes         
12    12 yes         
13    13 yes         
14    14 yes         
15    15 yes         
16    16 yes         
17    17 yes         
18    18 yes         
19    19 yes         
20    20 yes
```